# Best way to host stateful websocket servers that need to be connected to individually on Google cloud platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, websocket

I'm building a websocket server and I'd like to deploy it on GCP and be able to connect users to the same server instance. I can't figure out how to do this.

An example of how this could be used is: Multiple users connecting to the same chat room instance. They need to connect to the same server and then the server can handle broadcasting new chat messages to connected users.

Comment: Using a Stateful MIG with load balancer will help you in this case, In load balancer you can use Session affinity option to redirect the traffic to a particular instance. As per the official [doc](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity):


Session affinity allows you to control how the load balancer selects backends for new connections in a predictable way as long as the number of healthy backends remains constant. This is useful for applications that need multiple requests from a given user to be directed to the same backend or endpoint. Such application

Comment: The following steps helps you in deploying your application:

Create a VM image that can be used to deploy your application.
Create an MIG template and specify the VM image in that template.
Now create a MIG using the template and attach a load balancer to the MIG.
Configure the Session affinity for your load balancer and use this in your application to achieve the desired goal.

In your scenario, since you are using websockets which work based on TCP connections you can use TCP load balancer for your Stateful MIG and configure Session affinity for your TCP load balancer.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni Can I use session affinity to get different users to connect to the same backend? It doesn't seem like I can according to the docs.

Comment: Actually you need to use http(s) load balancer, The HTTP(S) proxy uses a URL map to make a routing determination based on HTTP attributes (such as the request path, cookies, or headers). Based on the routing decision, the proxy forwards client requests to specific backend services or backend buckets. The URL map can specify additional actions, such as sending redirects to clients. [Source](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#:~:text=The%20HTTP(S)%20proxy%20uses,as%20sending%20redirects%20to%20clients).

Comment: So you can use cookies for redirecting and Session affinity to maintain persistence.